# R include "#" in R manual hyperref

Tags: r, devtools, roxygen2

I am attempting to include a hyperref link in R documentation using roxygen2 and devtools in a repo.  [Here's a dummy version](https://github.com/trinker/dummy).

```
#' Test
#' 
#' Test 2
#' 
#' @param x An object
#' @section Suggestion: Looky here: 
#' \enumerate{ 
#'   \item{\bold{Item 1} - Foo}
#'   \item{\bold{Item 2} - Bar:  
#'   \href{https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#installation}{click me}}   
#' }
#' @export 
test <- function(x = "test") {
    print(x)
}
```

I run

```
library(roxygen2)
roxygenize("C:/Users/trinker/GitHub/dummy")
```

And then in R studio use check and out pops this error:

```
* checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
This typically indicates Rd problems.
LaTeX errors found:
! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.61 me}

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.61 me}

! Illegal parameter number in definition of \Hy@tempa.
<to be read again> 
                   i
l.61 me}

* checking PDF version of manual without hyperrefs or index ... ERROR

Exited with status 1.




Files
Plots
Help




New Folder


Delete


Rename


More




C:  Users   trinker GitHub  dummy   R


Name
Size    Modified

..


dummy-package.R
109 bytes
May 31, 2013, 12:51 PM


test.R
324 bytes
May 31, 2013, 12:56 PM


ConsoleC:/Users/trinker/GitHub/dummy/
```

SO I escape the `#` and it runs:

```
#' Test
#' 
#' Test 2
#' 
#' @param x An object
#' @section Suggestion: Looky here: 
#' \enumerate{ 
#'   \item{\bold{Item 1} - Foo}
#'   \item{\bold{Item 2} - Bar:  
#'   \href{https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/\#installation}{click me}}   
#' }
#' @export 
test <- function(x = "test") {
    print(x)
}
```

[PDF looks good](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61803503/dummy.pdf) and hypref works.  But then if I do:

```
library(dummy)
?dummy::test
```

The hyperef `click me` is broke and results in:

```
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js//#installation
```

Rather than:

```
https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/#installation
```

As produced by the pdf (LaTeX link).

How can I appropriately escape the pound sign (`#`) so both the pdf and html documentation heyperlinks work?

I put the devtools and roxygen2 tags on but I don't think they're relevant to this problem.

Session info as requested:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.0 (2013-04-03)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] dummy_0.1.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.0.0
```

Comment: Can you provide `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: @Dason are you unable to replicate this?  I posted the session info above.

Comment: The orignal version works fine for me on my wife's mac running 2.15.  I'll check on my windows machine later...

Comment: I can reproduce your error using Windows + R-3.0 though.

Comment: What does that mean?  Is this a bug?